# How to save entry to the current site from the front end?

Tags: multi-site, entry-form

I have a multi site setup and a front facing entry form, which saves entries always to the same site (and not the current one which is weird).

Is there a way to define to which site the current entry should be saved? Something in the lines of:

```
{{ csrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/save-entry">
<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="site" value="{{ currentSite.id }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter is called `siteId`

```TWIG
<input type="hidden" name="siteId" value="{{ currentSite.id }}">
```